# Adding Dates in R

Tags: r, date

I have the following dataset:

```
Data <- data.frame(
  date = c("2001-1", "2001-2", "2001-3", "2001-1", "2001-2", "2001-3", "2001-1", "2001-2", "2001-3"),
  actor = c("A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C", "A", "B", "C"),
  cat = c("I", "II", "III", "I", "II", "III", "I", "II", "III"),
  freq = c(2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 5, 2, 6, 3)
)
```

There are actors (A, B and C), who address three topics (I, II or III) differently (see freq).

Now I want to combine the three months (2001-1, 2001-2 and 2001-3) per actor to one quarter per actor. In order to do so, also the frequency counts have to be summed.

How can I combine three months to a quarter?
How do I sum up the frequency-counts per quarter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To convert year-months to quarters you may try this:

```
library(zoo)
Data$qtr <- as.yearqtr(df$date,  "%Y-%m")

# sum up the frequency-counts per quarter
aggregate(freq ~ qtr, data = Data, sum)
```

Comment: To be honest I am not quite sure how you want to aggregate your data after reading your question and your comments to @Matthew Plourde...Well, hope you get the code you want in the end.

Answer (score 1):

```
aggregate(freq ~ actor + quarter +cat, 
          data=transform(Data, quarter=quarters(as.Date(paste(date, '1', sep='-')))), 
          sum)
#   actor quarter cat freq
# 1     A      Q1   I    5
# 2     B      Q1  II   11
# 3     C      Q1 III   12
```

`quarters` takes a `Date` object and returns its calendar year quarter number. In order to convert your month strings to `Date`s in base R, we need to add a day.

Comment: that looks great, thank you. but what about "cat"? is there no need to mention "cat" in the expression?

Comment: Why do you want me to mention `cat`?

Comment: because I also need "cat" in my dataset. your output only gives me "actor", "quarter" and "freq". but "cat" is missing.

Comment: better, but it adds all the quarter of all years into one.